# Google Sheets Script - Finding and Clearing/Editing cells that match a criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a macro for my spreadsheet, however I have no idea how to write script. What I want to do, is have a macro (activated by drawing) to find specific checkboxes, change their value, and also clear the contents of specific nearby cells.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raARw.png)

This is an example of my spreadsheet with all the information stripped out of it.

Essentially, I want to find the checkbox in the green cells next to the "Title", change their value to FALSE, and then delete the contents of "Data1" and "Data2". The Title and Label cells are the same for every iteration, so I'm sure that they could be used as identifier.

I don't know how to write script, so I opted to just manually recording it and replaying it.

```
function ClearCells() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E6:G6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('C5:C6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');
};
```

(repeated, as needed)

The problem I have with this, is that I am continuously adding more to the spreadsheet, which would require constant updates to the macro to include them. I'd like the macro to be able to find and change them automatically, without me having to change the code upon any additions.

Thank you for any and all help, and I hope I was able to explain things properly!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the current issue of your script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't explain it well, I'm unfamiliar with proper terminology and how to correctly describe it. I want to find checkboxes, change their values to FALSE, and delete cells nearby them.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I want to find checkboxes`, in your sample image, for example, there are checkboxes "C5:C6" and "F7". In this case, do you want to set both checkboxes to `FALSE`? And, do you want to reflect this to all checkboxes in a sheet? First, I would like to correctly understand your expected result. I apologize for this.

Comment: I want to change the checkbox in "C5:C6" to FALSE, and clear cells "E6:G6". I do not want to change "F7". I would like to do this across the whole sheet. ("C11:C12" FALSE , clear "E12:G12" , "C17:C18" FALSE , clear "E18:G18" , "J5:J6" FALSE , clear "L6:N6" ... etc.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I want to change the checkbox in "C5:C6" to FALSE, and clear cells "E6:G6". I do not want to change "F7". I would like to do this for every similar situation. ("C11:C12" FALSE , clear "E12:G12" , "C17:C18" FALSE , clear "E18:G18" , "J5:J6" FALSE , clear "L6:N6" ... etc.)

I would like to propose the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and please set the sheet name, and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const ranges = sheet.createTextFinder("Title").matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findAll();
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  const { checkboxes, dataCells } = ranges.reduce((o, r) => {
    o.checkboxes.push(r.offset(0, -1, 2, 1).getA1Notation());
    o.dataCells.push(r.offset(1, 1, 1, 3).getA1Notation());
    return o;
  }, { checkboxes: [], dataCells: [] });
  sheet.getRangeList(checkboxes).setValue(false);
  sheet.getRangeList(dataCells).clearContent();
}
```

- When this script is run, the cells of "Title" are searched by TextFinder. And, create the ranges for checkboxes and the data cells are created. And, those cells are updated by RangeList.

#### Note:

- In your sample image, it seems that the merged cells are used. If the above script cannot be used, it might be required to confirm the sample Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. It works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkboxlocationarray() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const tf = sh.createTextFinder("Title").matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  let locA = tf.map(rg => rg.offset(0,-1).getA1Notation());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(locA));
}
```